# How to speed up computational time of a huge function (500+ terms)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a function (3 space dimensions + 1 dimension time) with a huger number of terms (500+): it is mainly a sum of many exponential functions.

Of course, I need to compute a huger number of times. 
For now I am using a compiled form and then a ParallelTable like that (funcx, funy and funz are the functions which involved many terms):

```
  MyFuncCompiled=Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}, {t111, _Real}},Chop[(Funcx[x, y, z, t111] + Funcy[x, y, z, t111] + Funcz[x, y, z, t111])/3],Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C"];

  ParallelTable[MyFuncCompiled[i, j, k, h]; {i, -Pi/2, 3 Pi/2 - Step, Step}, {j, -Pi/2,3 Pi/2 - Step, Step}, {k, Pi/2, 5 Pi/2 - Step, Step}, {h, -16, 16,8}];
```

I already tried Simplify and FullSimplfy (on the Funcx ... functions) but there is no simplification to make.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately it is not planned :(

Comment: You could always steal it :)

Comment: (i give you +1, hope someone solves your problem or steals a mainframe for you).